# Iphone Apps Upgrade check

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, migration

How to detect the upgrade point in objective C ? Is there anyways to detect that app has just upgraded to newer version or update is in progress. ?

My scenario is this consider a user have an application version 1.0 in his device and he's getting update notification and updating the app. Here after the version update app should have to show some app tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NSUserDefaults` to check if app is launching for first time.

```
//In applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:
BOOL hasLaunchedBefore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"AppHasLaunchedBefore_v1.0"];
if(!hasLaunchedBefore) {
    //First launch
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"AppHasLaunchedBefore_v1.0"];
}
else {
    //Not first launch
}
```

When you update the app to version 2.0(let's say) modify the above key to `AppHasLaunchedBefore_v2.0`. This way for first launch after update, this key will not be present in the `NSUserDefaults` making `hasLaunchedBefore = NO`. You can take the necessary action.

If required, you can remove the previous version key from the `NSUserDefaults` with,

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"AppHasLaunchedBefore_v1.0"];
```

---

You can programmatically get the bundle version of current released app with,

```
NSString* version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
//Append this to the user default key, AppHasLaunchedBefore_v%@
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any way to check this without hardcoding the versions. I may release my version frequently. A user may do upgrade version 1.0 to 3.1 directly without upgrading it to 2.0 or some other

Comment: @nik your app should know before hand what version to check for in the user defaults. That code will need to be modified for each update you push to app store. So I guess it should not matter if you hard code it.

Comment: Yes your scenario will help only if I am releasing fresh version of app. If suppose am checking, adding this condition in my 3rd version of app then it will not help right

Comment: @nik It will because in 3rd version you will check for key `AppHasLaunchedBefore_v3.0`. After update, the very first run, app will check and this key will not be present. So your code can safely assume its first launch after app update.

Comment: Checking is there any dynamic way or delegate method something like that to identify upgrade alone without making any service calls. Even if a user killed his app and launching it again also this condition will be triggered.

Comment: @nik Not that I am aware of. There is no way to determine using any framework APIs.

Comment: great amar u got the point now. So here cosider a user is directly installing the 3rd version of app. So there we are not updating just installing in newly right but as per your condition it is not checking the update just an installation

Comment: @nik Won't reading another key help? Something like `ApplicationHasLaunchedEver`? Then check for individual version? Just a thought.